# unable to login with default user name administrator after installing Kentico

Tags: kentico

I have installed the Kentico and it generated an URL. When we try to login with a default username 'administrator' and getting an error message as follow.

[WebFarmTaskManager.CanCreateTask]: Task type 'DICTIONARYCOMMAND' is not supported. The task needs to be registered with WebFarmHelper.RegisterTask method.

[image]

Comment: What version of Kentico are you using? And what is the environment you are running Kentico?This error usually occurs in two cases: 
1. When the application start is too slow or too fast and the application is not initialized correctly. How was the instance installed? 
2. If there is some custom code in place, or some custom assemblies and they are not loaded correctly during the startup.

Comment: I am using the trial version of Kentico 11. I am running in locally. I have verified the prerequisites of the local environment.

Comment: What options were selected and not selected when installing?

Answer (score 0):

Publish first CMSApp_AppCode, then, in the same folder, CMSApp, however disable the option "Delete all existing files prior to publish" in CMSApp